# How do keep window always at bottom?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, window, window-manager

I've got a terminal with the menubar and titlebar hidden and has `cbonsai` running on repeat. I'd like to keep it always behind any other windows, and maybe also prevent it from showing in the alt-tab menu. Arch Linux KDE 5

Comment: I know of termoid https://github.com/koldbyte/termoid and I do use it, but I'd prefer something more general